# How To Install Apps Without Sudo or Admin Privileges

Tags: permissions, software-installation, deb, deepin

I want to install a Game Client thing called Steam ([here](https://store.steampowered.com/about)). It downloads a .deb package but needs root or admin password to install. I need a way to install and get Steam working without admin or root password. Are there any terminal commands I can utilize to do this? I am running Deepin 15.11 with the latest everything.

Comment: No way! (+6 symbols)

Comment: So there is no way?

Comment: Is flatpak already installed?

Comment: No, Flatpak also needs root to install, and as you know I don't have root

Comment: Your only other option would be to download the source for Steam and build it yourself; not an easy task by any stretch. Curious - is this a workplace PC?

Comment: It is an old laptop that I just received but I am not root. Definitely not a workplace PC

Comment: Where would I get the Source, and how would I go from there after I get it?

Comment: @LinuxMachine: recover the root password.  The machine is going to be a paperweight without root privileges.

Comment: @LinuxMachine You can also just reinstall Deepin (or install any other Distro) and replace the old installation and set the root password yourself.

Answer (score 0):

the steam .deb file installs a launcher that sets up and mintains the steam user environment for each user.  it's probably possible to install without admin support

The install consists of a shell script and a binary the has the following dependancies:

```
 ldd /usr/lib/games/steam/steam
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf76e1000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf716f000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7166000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7111000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf710c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf6f92000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf6f75000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf6dbd000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6d91000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf76e3000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6d73000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf6d6f000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf6d66000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0xf6d4a000)
```

which to me look like common libraries to me.

It should be possible to extract script and binary from the deb (eg: use cpio(CLI) or file-roller(GUI)) and then install the binary under your home and modify the script to point to it.

Oh yeah it's 32-bit so you'll be installing a whole heap of extra stuff manually, and messing with LD_LIBRARY_PATH if your system doesn't have 32 bit support installed (this will be hard)

But really you should be trying to get admin permission on that machine (if you own it) or asking the real admin to assist you (if you don't).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an [AppImage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppImage) but they don't make one. AppImage runs as a regular user and is super easy to "install". Maybe pester Valve to do the right thing.

However, if you download the Steam .deb file you can extract it like so:

```bsh
$ mkdir steam
$ cd steam
$ ar x ~/Downloads/steam_latest.deb
$ tar xvf data.tar.xz && rm data.tar.xz
$ cd usr/bin
$ ./steam
```

Now whether or not it can run depends on what's installed on the machine. If you have all the libraries then Steam will update itself. If you don't, you're going to get "Steam needs to install these additional packages" and a list of packages. This requires root unfortunately. You can close/cancel the Package Install window and Steam will still run and update itself but you're likely to run in to trouble when trying to actually use it.

If you're still dead set on making it work, it is possible to download each of those requirement .deb packages, extract them then set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the extracted lib directories so that steam will load the libraries from your home directory. This takes some work and I'm not sure I should even attempt to explain it.